Receiving a parcel while touring France
We are currently travelling through France to Spain in our motorhome (RV). Our leisure battery charger has failed, so I need one sent over to us from the U.K. I’ve heard there are ‘Point Relais’ lockers at various locations, but French customs take around 2 weeks to assess each package before releasing it for final delivery. We therefore want to have it delivered as far south as possible, so that it’s there by the time we get there (as we only drive for 2 hours each day)! But how do we get one of the lockers to give as an address, whithout physically being there and who gives us the code to open it?

Is it feasible to get it delivered to your Spanish address?

Can you buy it from a shop in the European Customs Union (almost, but not exactly, the same as the Schengen area)? - there will be less delays. Also, if you are staying in caravan parks, they might accept deliveries for you

2 weeks seems excessive for a package to go through customs, most will get through instantaneously if the correct paperwork has been done. But it may also mean you have taxes to pay. It would probably be much easier if you could source the item from a reseller in France or elsewhere in the EU.

@DidierL, the OP stated that it was the charger that needed replacement, not the battery.  Depending on what charger it is and how it needs to interface with his motorhome, it could certainly be possible that the UK might be the only source for a piece of equipment like that.

@Milwrdfan oh yes my bad

“Point relais” is basically French for a pick-up point offered by a parcel delivery service. Many online retailers now charge for home deliveries and offer this as a cheaper alternative, which seems to have become more common in France than elsewhere.
The way you use them is by selecting a specific “point relais” in a list when placing your order (typically you see them on a map around the delivery address you entered, with opening times and other info). Whether you can use that and which “point relais” is available is specific to each retailer.
Most are not lockers but small shops that do that to drive foot traffic and a little bit of additional income. The post office itself also offers a similar option for its Colissimo delivery service. If it is an automated locker, you might get a one-time code by email or SMS when the parcel has been delivered. It is then available for a few days up to two weeks at most before being returned to the sender.
So a “point relais” is not a locker that would be available to you long term or an address you could use with regular postal services or for any arbitrary delivery and I am not sure this would really solve your problem.

Also most will only keep items for a few days (rules vary greatly), probably not 2 weeks.

@jcaron 10 to 14 days is common in my experience.

I think I have seen at least one which had (official) rules saying 5 business days, and even 3 for lockers IIRC. No idea whether they actually keep them longer.

@jcaron I wasn't thinking about lockers specifically but pick-up in general, including Colissimo, which is the one I use most often (10 business days so effectively two weeks). It seems the delay is indeed shorter for lockers (e.g. Mondial Relay, 5 calendar days — not even business days — vs. 8 for a regular collection point). I edited the answer to clarify this.

@jcaron OP doesn't actually need the item held at a pickup point for 2 weeks. Rather, 2 weeks is the estimated delay in delivery due to customs. The holding period will only be whatever amount OP conservatively overestimates the delivery time. And, if OP has the option to speed up or slow down the RV tour somewhat based on updated shipping information, they could arrange to "meet" the package more precisely, further reducing the risk of having it returned to sender.

@DidierL OP needs a new charger, not a new battery.

@DidierL That's really the seller's problem, the gist of the answer is that it's not something you can set up yourself, it's just a delivery mode a retailer might or might not offer.

@nanoman jcaron was merely reacting to what I wrote in the answer as the holding period can be a bit shorter than what I originally suggested.

You should be able to use the "Poste restante" service.
I say should because there is very little recent information about it online (other than the "transfer mail sent to my home address to poste restante" service), but it is still in the official price list (page 18):

POSTE RESTANTE
Service de réception du courrier ou colis en bureau de poste.

Modalités : Aucune démarche préalable nécessaire
Adressage : S'il y a plusieurs bureaux de poste dans la commune, mentionner le nom du bureau de poste.


There is a cost of:

1.49€ per piece of mail
0.76€ per newspaper
5.72€ per parcel

So basically you just give as address:
first name last name
POSTE RESTANTE
name of the post office if several in the city
(possibly address of the post office, but it should not be needed)
postal code city

Note that:

They will only keep things for 2 weeks (I think)
This will only work if the parcel is sent via the postal service (i.e. Royal Mail), not by courriers (e.g. UPS, Fedex...). Note that I'm not sure if Parcelforce qualifies as the former or the latter (they supposedly deliver via GLS in Europe, which would mean not postal service).
It may complicate things if there are taxes to pay
Some senders may refuse such addresses (like they would refuse PO Boxes etc.) for a variety of reasons (most often if they use couriers, who cannot deliver to such addresses).
French Post offices may not be open when you expect them to be (e.g. on Saturday afternoon). Some may have even more restricted hours.
You will need some form of ID to collect the item
It would probably be easier if you have the item's tracking number (both to know when the item arrives and to facilitate retrieval).

But all in all, I would still recommend you find a seller in France (or the EU), it would probably make things easier and quicker.
